# How to read an HTML list from a webpage into R

Tags: r, web-scraping, xml2

Consider a website that has 4 or more lists `<li>` html elements. 
For example a website like this: https://www.cprd.com/bibliography/bibliography.html

Using `xml2` (or other approach, but `xml2` and piping is preferred), what is the best way to extract the list into a vector of characters?

```
url <- 'https://www.cprd.com/bibliography/bibliography.html'
library(xml2) 
page <- read_html(url)
```

The output should be a list of `<li>` lists on the website. (there is one list for each year)

And the first list should have a first item equal to 'Assessment of channeling bias among initiators of glucose-lowering drugs: A UK cohort study. 
Ankarfeldt MZ, Thorsted BL, Groenwold RH, Adalsteinsson E, Ali MS, Klungel OH. 
Clin Epidemiol. 2017;9:19–30.'

EDIT: comments propose

```
library(rvest)
output<-page %>% html_nodes('ol') %>% lapply(html_nodes, 'li') %>% lapply(html_text, trim = TRUE)
output[[1]][1]

[1] "Assessment of channeling bias among initiators of glucose-lowering drugs: A UK cohort study. \r\n        Ankarfeldt MZ, Thorsted BL, Groenwold RH, Adalsteinsson E, Ali MS, Klungel OH. Clin Epidemiol. 2017;9:19㤼㸶30."
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Try using the [`rvest`](http://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/) package for this: `library(rvest); read_html('https://www.cprd.com/bibliography/bibliography.html') %>%
    html_nodes('ol') %>%
    lapply(., function(x) html_nodes(x,'li') %>% html_text())`.

Comment: @Abdou If you `lapply` (or `purrr::map`, which as the situation gets more complicated will become more convenient) twice, the code will be easier to read: `h2 %>% html_nodes('ol') %>% lapply(html_nodes, 'li') %>% lapply(html_text, trim = TRUE)` Time-wise, they're pretty much identical.

Answer (score 3):

Using `rvest` (that's a slight improvement over `xml2`):

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.cprd.com/bibliography/bibliography.html'

page <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('ol') %>% 
  map(~html_nodes(.x, 'li') %>% 
        html_text() %>% 
        gsub(pattern = '\\t|\\r|\\n', replacement = '')
  )
```

That `gsub` takes care of taking out special characters, as 'new line' and 'tabulation'